# unload resources from specific page - React SPA

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

In single page application, I need to unload specific script when user goes to specific page

My script loads when the app is initialised in app.jsx, So these scripts will always be there.

script is in  example: `<script id="" src="" type="text/javascript" async=""></script>`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to unload scripts in specific page? e.g <script id="" src="" type="text/javascript" async=""></script>

Answer (score 0):

you can unload your script like this:
Unmount the components that you want from the same DOM element that you mounted.
Ex:-

```
ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById('example'));
```

then unmount it-

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('example'));
```